# Как сделать rtl в woocommerce price slider?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Как сделать слайдер цены в rtl (изменить ползунок с маленького на большой)?

Я нашел, что это джейквери виджет, но где именно нужно его заменить?

Вот как думаю менять: keith-wood.name/rtlsliders.html

Answer (score 1):

подключите новый js файл к теме, с помощью `wp_enqueue_script`. Потом найдите место в теме где у вас там идет инициализация слайдера, и как параметр допишите там `isRTL: true`. Если верить тому что написано по той ссылке что вы указали.

Цитата из вашего линка:
*Connect the right-to-left slider functionality to your divisions.
`$(selector).slider({isRTL: true});`*